# Spring Annotation Config with Multiple JPA Persistence Units Doesn't Persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

I started out with [this guide](http://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa), to migrate our xml config to an annotation config.

The current **problem** is, that my test a persist seems to not actually write the data (= no transaction commit). This results in the next check to fail. The environment currently has five persistence units and according entityManagerFactories and transactionManagers.

*MyTest.java*

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PersistenceJPAConfig.class}, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyDao testable;

    @Transactional(transactionManager = "tm1") // tried with name= and without
    @Test
    public void crudTest() throws Exception {
        // assert that the table is empty
        List<MyDO> all = testable.getAll();
        assertTrue(all.isEmpty());

        // write one entity
        MyDO anEntity = new MyDO();
        testable.persist(anEntity);

        // load all entities and assert that the details match
        List<MyDO> allAfterInsert = testable.getAll();
        // THIS FAILS
        assertFalse("The database result should not be empty.", allAfterInsert.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

*PersistenceJPAConfig.java*

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("my.package")
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPersistenceUnit") // also tried 
    @Bean(name = "myEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"my.package"});
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("myPersistenceUnit");

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    // ... the same for the other persistenceUnits with increasing names

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean(name = "tm1")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getNativeEntityManagerFactory());
        transactionManager.setPersistenceUnitName("myPersistenceUnit");
        transactionManager.afterPropertiesSet();
        return transactionManager;
    }

    // ... the same for the other persistenceUnits with increasing names

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

MyDao.java

```
public class MyDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPersistenceUnit")
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "tm1") // also tried with different variations like above
    public Long persist(final MyDO entity) {
        em.persist(entity); // tried to add an em.flush(), but that throws a TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
        // handling transactions would throw IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead
        return entity.getId();
    }
}
```

The persistence units are located in the file `META-INF/persistence.xml`.

The tests worked with the xml configuration, but don't work with my current annotation config. Is there something I forgot? What more information could I provide?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: Instead of `entityManagerFactory().getNativeEntityManagerFactory()` I used `entityManagerFactory().getObject()` and everything works as expected.

```
@Bean(name = "tm1")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    transactionManager.setPersistenceUnitName("myPersistenceUnit");
    transactionManager.afterPropertiesSet();
    return transactionManager;
}
```

I am not sure why though.